# How to resurrect one's Amazon Reading List data in Shelfari?

Tags: amazon

As some of you may know, **Amazon Reading List** was a [LinkedIn app](http://www.linkedin.com/opensocialInstallation/preview?applicationId=1700) that disappeared from LinkedIn recently (early 2013, I think).

<sup>(The app page still exists, but if you try to "add" the application, you get an error:

 `You have reached the limit of applications on your homepage and your profile. Please remove an application from both pages before adding another application.`)</sup>

I kinda liked the app, and had dozens of books listed in it as "read" or "want to read". I had put a little effort in writing some reviews, too.

Now, at a [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402934/how-to-get-linkedin-amazon-reading-list-data) I just saw this interesting comment:

> The previous Reading List data can now be resurrected at Amazon's
>   [shelfari.com](http://www.shelfari.com/)

I registered to Shelfari (using existing Amazon account), which seems pretty nice and usable. I was looking for an option to **find/import my old Amazon Reading List data**, but couldn't find it. Anyone know how to do this, if it's indeed possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, turns out it can be done very easily at http://www.shelfari.com/addbooks where there's an option **Import Your LinkedIn Reading List**. Clicking "Import" will bring you to an import view like this:

[image]

There's a FAQ item about this too: [Reading List (LinkedIn) Import](http://www.shelfari.com/help/question117).

I just tried it and my books and reviews got imported just fine.

Comment: This option doesn't seem to work anymore since the link from shelfari to import list from linkedin is broken now. Any other options to try ? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After importing reading list from LinkedIn to shelfari (and adding other books) you can then use your public shelf as one of the websites that you add to LinkedIn.